# How to set all network adapters to private from batch or powershell?

Tags: networking, powershell, batch, network-adapter

I have a very simple question:

I'm currently setting a specific network adapter to private like this from a batch script:

```
powershell -command Set-NetConnectionProfile -Name "Network" -NetworkCategory Private
```

How can I do this for all network adapters without knowing the names or anything about them?

Comment: Use a power shell command or netsh wlan command to first list all the wireless profiles and go from there.  netsh wlan show profiles

Comment: This is not about wireless profiles.

Comment: Wired profiles (any time I have looked) are set to Private by default.

Comment: I've set up about 100 VMs with Windows 10 this month. The wired profiles were public by default every time. Windows does however ask if you want to make it private on the first boot.

Comment: I'm not sure. I have VMware here and wired profiles for virtual machines are private by default. So I do not know in your situation.

Comment: I don't know, maybe you installed some sort of guest tools. I'm just using kvm.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
Get-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceAlias "Network" | Set-NetConnectionProfile -NetworkCategory Private -Confirm:$false -PassThru
```

Usually (*almost every time*), where there's a `Set-*`, there's a `Get-*`. PowerShell cmdlets output *Objects* that can be chained (*piped*) to it's corresponding `Verb-Noun` cmdlet.

- `Get-NetConnectionProfile` in this case, returns the connection profiles that have an interface name of *"Network"*.
- `Set-ConnectionProfile`. When piped to this cmdlet, you are able to grab the entirety of the object from `Get-NetConnectionProfile`, and modify it. I.e: setting it to *Private*.

Comment: This will only change category for the *one* interface labeled "Network", not all.

Comment: @Dennis, Ok? Remove the parameter and get all profiles.

Comment: @'Abraham Zinala', Yes, that would be an answer to the question...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally found a way. I couldn't figure out how to iterate over the Names, but I found a way to iterate over the InterfaceAliases. I had to adjust the Set-NetConnectionProfile call accordingly, but now it works like a charm:

```
for /F "skip=3 tokens=1,2,3* delims= " %%G in ('netsh interface show interface') DO (
    echo "Setting %%J to private..."
    powershell -command Set-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceAlias "Network" -NetworkCategory Private
)
```

See interface loop came from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42654438/2879085

Answer (score 0):

```
powershell -c "get-netconnectionprofile | foreach{Set-netconnectionprofile -InterfaceIndex $_.InterfaceIndex -NetworkCategory Private}"
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles").Name | foreach{REG ADD "$_" /v "Category" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).